# Solve the equation in $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

The problem is taken from my textbook in algebra and is given as:

Solve $x+4=3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$

From the euclidean algorithm I found that $2=4^{-1}\bmod(7)$

Now I'm not completly sure how to continue but I tried:
$$x+4+4^{-1}=3+4^{-1} $$
$$x=3+4^{-1}=3+2=5   $$

However, the correct answer is $x=6$ and I'm not sure were I went wrong since the book don't have any examples so I would appreciate some help!

Comment: $x+4\equiv 3\iff x\equiv -1$.   And, of course, $-1\equiv 6$. All congruences being taken $\pmod 7$.

Comment: You're confusing the reciprocal and the negative.

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: @wroom You are confusing the *multiplicative* inverse with the *additive* inverse

Comment: Oh I see, haven't really gotten so far yet but will retry with additive inverse then!

Comment: @BillDubuque It's a swedish book but the name abstrakt algebra :)

Comment: Recall that $a + (-a) = 0$.  Recall that $a\times (a^{-1}) = 1$.  Don't confuse these.

Comment: So, we have $x+4\equiv 3\pmod{7}$ implies that $x+4+(-4)\equiv 3+(-4)\pmod{7}$.  Simplifying, we have $x\equiv -1\pmod{7}$ and if we wanted to, we can add $7$ since that is effectively the same as adding zero in the context of $\Bbb Z_7$ to get $x\equiv -1+7\equiv 6\pmod{7}$.  This is all just a long-winded way of saying "*you can subtract the same thing from both sides.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solve $x+4=3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$

$(x+4)+3=3+3$

$x+(4+3)=6$

$x+0=6\;,\;$ indeed in $\;\mathbb{Z}_{7}\;,\;4+3=0\;.$

$x=6\;.$